# Credit Migration: Risk

Tags: risk-management, credit-risk, default-probability

Hi I am given two tables  of two tables showing data about fictional corporate business partners and relevant credit risk data – ID, rating, probability of default (PD, defined by rating), loss given default % (LGD), original exposure (on- and off-balance sheet exposures), exposure at default (EAD), risk-weighted assets (RWA), capital requirement (8% x RWA), expected loss (EL defined as EADxPDxLGD), EADxPD and EADxLGD.

I am wondering how can I identify the extent of credit risk migration between the two periods– Period1 and Period2 – from the data in the two tables (Specific Business Partners are identified by the field ID). The user has a number of alternatives for defining the migration impact and should provide not only a result in terms of increased risk-weight (RWA/EAD), increased probability of default and expected loss, but also consider the impact of new and existing customers and describe the impact of defaulted and unrated customers and whether they are relevant to the analysis by considering the effects on PD, RWA and EL.  Which customers have increased/decreased capital consumption the most?

Comment: This doesn't add much to the other question. What is the concrete problem you're struggling with.

Comment: I want to compute the effect of migration on probability of default

Comment: Then explain what prevents you from calculating.

Comment: I am new to this field and I was wondering if I can get some R/python code for similar analysis

Comment: or perhaps some literature that is useful

Comment: There is some R-code in the linked question, if I understand this exercise correctly it will be more valuable for you to do the analysis yourself as opposed to reading a book about it. You need to get to know your data.